# C# Path CsvReader - how to use absolute path

Tags: c#, csv, path, streamreader, absolute-path

I'm using System.IO.StreamReader passing a string path (@"‪C:\Users\someuser\somefolder\my.csv")

```
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filepath))
        {
            var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
            var entries = csvReader.GetRecords<SpreadsheetEntry>();
            return entries.ToList();
        }
```

this throws the following exception:

```
System.IO.IOException
```

HResult=0x8007007B
  Message=The **filename, directory** name, or volume label syntax is **incorrect** :

**'C:\Users\someuser\Source\Repos\StakeParser\StakeParser\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\‪C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\testspreadsheet.csv'**
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
  .....

**My question is, how do i use this correclty so that I can later pass the fullpath as an argument in the console? , at the moment its starting from the working path instead of taking the absoluth path...**

Comment: pls post ALL the relevant code

Comment: all there: 1) path string 2) StreamReader that takes the string and throws the error 3) Exception and details, basically it says there no file at that path because its combining the app path with the filepath that is passed to the StreamReader.

Comment: are you sure all the code is there. The path that you are passing and the path being thrown in the exception tells that the path is being set incorrectly. If you had earlier set the correct path, then chances are `CSVReader` class is taking the path from somewhere else.

Comment: please check the second line of my question. That is the only thing in the string im passing to the reader. The reader then does the concat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is provided here. Streamreader adds the absolute path to the working path its running at.

http://www.introprogramming.info/tag/streamreader-class/

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Users\someuser\Source\Repos\StakeParser\StakeParser\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\‪C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\testspreadsheet.csv`

Look carefully at the filepath variable `StreamReader(filepath)` it is 2 paths combined together:

```
C:\Users\someuser\Source\Repos\StakeParser\StakeParser\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\

C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\testspreadsheet.csv
```

I am guessing you just want the 2nd part of it. Somewhere before the code shown you likely concatenated the current working directory and a filename, but that filename was already an entire path.

.NET has the Path class the is very useful for handling paths: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path

Comment: I will check the path class. I think you didnt understand. Look at the first lines in my question : im passing a path not doing anything with that string after. The reader then concatenates the two paths. Why? I dont know, that is my question. Seems the path starts from the app folder, so it take sthat path and the add the path i give the reader...

Comment: to make it very simple to understand i make this: 
new StreamReader(@"‪C:\Users\someuser\somefolder\my.csv");
and get and exception saying this:
HResult=0x8007007B Message=The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect :

'C:\Users\someuser\Source\Repos\StakeParser\StakeParser\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\‪C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\testspreadsheet.csv'

Comment: You have not posted all of the important code - the most likely problem here is that the variable filepath is NOT set how you mention. StreamReader works fine if you pass it a valid path. Set a breakpoint in your debugger and look at filepath, then go back to where it is being set and fix it.

Comment: If the filepath is correct at the start of the code shown, then the other place to look is CsvReader - that is not a standard C# function. Are you using a library?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes C# does not allow to read data from C:\Users... folder.

Use some other folder like D:\SomeFolder.

It will solve the problem.